# JQuery tablesorter using ajax and dynamic thead and tbody sections

Tags: jquery, ajax, dojo, rally, tablesorter

I am attempting to add in some table sorting using the jquery tablesorter plugin to a Rally app using dojo, struggling with how to hook up the update callback for the tablesorter.

I have html that looks like this (thead and tbody are separated as they are being dynamically generated i.e. number of columns is not known in advance):

```
<table id='myTable' class='tablesorter'>
    <thead id='sort-head'></thead>
    <tbody id='sort-body'></tbody>
</table>
```

tablesorter init is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad() {
        var appCustom = new ReleaseScopeChange();
        appCustom.display(dojo.body());
    }
    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
    $(document).ready(function(){$("#myTable").tablesorter();});      
</script>
```

Code updating the thead/tbody

```
dojo.byId("sort-head").innerHTML = headresults; 
dojo.byId("sort-body").innerHTML = bodyresults; 
$('#myTable').trigger("update");
```

Now, the sorting never actually gets set up at all. If I add a static table I can get the sorting working perfectly, so I am assuming its related to timing between the ajax request and the update trigger.

I have looked through a lot of other answers on this and I'm really not sure what is missing.

Comment: Don't you use `$('#myTable').trigger("update")` inside ajax callback like here http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the original tablesorter, it would be better to just remove, and replace the entire table instead of updating the thead & tbody html separately; then reinitialize tablesorter on the new table.

Or you could [disable tablesorter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171530/remove-jquery-tablesorter-from-table/8177869#8177869), then reinitialize it.

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), use the [`updateAll` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#updateall) instead of `update`.

```
dojo.byId("sort-head").innerHTML = headresults; 
dojo.byId("sort-body").innerHTML = bodyresults; 
$('#myTable').trigger("updateAll");
```