# jQuery table sorter broken on dynamically built tables

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I need to build my table dynamically but sorting it is also a requirement.

I've had tablesorter working on many other tables, but those are static ones. I cannot get it to work on a dynamically built table using data received by Ajax. AFAIK you need to use `$('myTable').trigger('updateAll');` after modifying the data and that is [confirmed by the maintainer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20272207/3115701) of the tablesorter fork that I am using.

I've built a small demo on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kg4v10oq/3/).

Any ideas on how I can get this to sort dynamic tables or is it a bug? I'm using the latest release of the tablesorter plugin and `jQuery 1.10.1`.

EDITS:

1) I've also tried calling `$('myTable').trigger('destroy');` and then re-initialising it in replace of using the above `updateAll`.

2) I also tried waiting till after I had built the table to initialise the tablesorter plugin on it.

Comment: Please explain the downvote. My question is on topic, has a perfectly viable question, has an example of my issue with minimal relevant code, shows I have already tried, shows I have researched this and shows I am continuing to try resolving this by the edits I have made. What is the issue with it?

Comment: I could not solve the error. But I think I have spotted the problem. In console, tblHead shows '<tr></tr><th>....</th>..." etc. It seems that all th tags are outside tr tag. This must be causing the problem.

Comment: @T.Shah That is indeed the problem! I think the `<tr>` is having it's end tagged appended automatically, thus causing all my `<th>` cells being placed after it. If you would like to submit it as the answer I'll mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @T.Shah stated, in the `thead`, the `th`'s are added outside of the `tr`. This is happening because the `th`'s are being appended to the `thead` and not the `tr` in this code:

```
tblHead.append('<th>...</th>');
```

Change the build table code on these lines to make it work ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kg4v10oq/5/)):

```
// Begin the row
var html = '<tr>';

// Fill the table header (thead) row
for (var i = 0; headerColumns.length - 1 >= i; i++) {
  var id = headerColumns[i]['id'];
  var value = headerColumns[i]['value'];

  // Check to see if this column has an average avalible for it
  if (averages[id]) {
    value = 'Average: ' + averages[id] + '<br />' + value;
  }

  // Write the table head data
  html += '<th id="' + id + '"' + '>' + value + '</th>';
}

// End the row
tblHead.append(html + '</tr>');
```

In the `<tbody>`, the HTML for adding a row is incorrect, it should end with a `</tr>`

```
tblBody.append('<tr id="tblRow' + key + '"></td>');
```

Instead, use a string to build the row:

```
html = "";
// Fill the table body (tbody) with all required rows of data
for (var key in reportData) {
  // Some object properties are inherited, we don't want these
  if (!reportData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    continue;
  }

  // Create a new table body row
  html += '<tr id="tblRow' + key + '">';

  // Apply data to each column in the row
  for (var i = 0; reportData[key].length - 1 >= i; i++) {
    var id = reportData[key][i]['id'];
    var value = reportData[key][i]['value'];

    // Write the column data
    html += '<td id="' + id + '"' + '>' + value + '</td>';
  }
  html += '</tr>';
}
tblBody.append(html);
```

Then trigger an "updateAll".

The reason a string is used to build the HTML is because it is better to interact with the DOM as little as possible to get the best performance. Instead of appending each element, build a HTML string and add it once, or twice in this example - once for the `thead` and once for the `tbody`.

Comment: Ah yes, I got it working with a similar fix https://jsfiddle.net/kg4v10oq/6/
 It seems the `tr`'s end tag is automatically appended causing the `th`'s to be placed after it. Not sure how I was blind to see it either, I checked for that problem as well.